# investigation of librsvg-dev

Tags: application-development, png, svg

While testing the [node-librsvg](https://github.com/physikerwelt/node-rsvg), which provides a node interface to
convert svg to png images using librsvg-dev, I realized that it works
really well on Ubuntu 12 , but some images can not be converted with
Ubuntu 14.

Now, I'd like to track down the problem further.

Since I never worked on a similar problem before I have some fundamental questions to start with:

1. Is a bug tracker which could be used to report the
   problem?
2. Is there a test suite to test the librsvg-dev package?
3. Is there a way to rebuild the package from the latests sources?

Comment: Your formatting was close to accurate, but not quite, so I've improved it. Nice first question!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes writing down the question helps

1 -> https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=librsvg2-dev;dist=unstable

3 -> https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial and http :// ccm. net/faq/809-debian-apt-get-no-pubkey-gpg-error